# MVC 4 Flush/Empty/Clear DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable

Can somebody please explain why `Clear()` or `Dispose()` fail to flush a DataTable recordset?

I am using DataTable in an MVC 4 project like so `var tbl = new DataTable()` which is working fine for retrieving data, but for some reason when I use `tbl.Clear()` and `tbl.Dispose()` and then attempt to reuse `tbl` it still has the recordset from the previous query, why?

Can somebody please let me know how to flush/clear/empty the previous DataTable recordset?

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Please see example code below:

```
string name = "";
string password = "";

var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
var writer = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented };    

var tbl = new DataTable();

string strConn = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestConnection"].ToString();

var conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
using (conn)
{
    conn.Open();
    var cmd = new SqlCommand("GetUserLoginID", conn) {CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure};
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", uid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BID", bId);

    var userRecord = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    userRecord.Fill(tbl);
    conn.Close();

    if (tbl.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        var row = tbl.Rows[0];

        name = row["Name"].ToString();
        password = row["Password"].ToString();
        code = row["Code"].ToString();
    }

    tbl.Clear();
    tbl.Dispose();

    cmd = new SqlCommand("GetUserDetails", conn) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", code);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BID", bId);

    userRecord.Fill(tbl);

    if (tbl.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        var row = tbl.Rows[0];

        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement("Root");
        writer.WriteElementString("BID", row["BID"].ToString());
        writer.WriteElementString("Name", name);

    }
    else
    {
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement("Root");
        writer.WriteElementString("BID", "Error");
    }
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Close();
}
```

Comment: Don't you get an exception when calling the Clear method? Can you you show us more code.

Comment: Please see my amended post.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you always use the same `SqlDataAdapter`.
You created a new Command :

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("GetUserDetails", conn) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };
```

but you have to set userRecord with this new Command:

```
userRecord = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

Comment: Yes I'm reusing `SqlDataAdapter` but using a different Stored Procedure, so doesn't that overwrite the previous connection. I've tried adding `conn.Close()` and `conn.Open()` before calling `cmd = new SqlCommand("GetUserDetails", conn)` but still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my amended code, which addresses my issue. It would appear I wasn't calling the second stored procedure, therefore the DataTable `tbl` was not being filled with a second dataset.

```
string name = "";
string password = "";

var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
var writer = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented };    

var tbl = new DataTable();

string strConn = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestConnection"].ToString();

var conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
using (conn)
{
    conn.Open();
    var cmd = new SqlCommand("GetUserLoginID", conn) {CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure};
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", uid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BID", bId);

    var userRecord = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    userRecord.Fill(tbl);

    if (tbl.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        var row = tbl.Rows[0];

        name = row["Name"].ToString();
        password = row["Password"].ToString();
        code = row["Code"].ToString();
    }

    tbl.Clear();

    cmd = new SqlCommand("GetUserDetails", conn) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", code);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BID", bId);

    userRecord = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    userRecord.Fill(tbl);

    if (tbl.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        var row = tbl.Rows[0];

        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement("Root");
        writer.WriteElementString("BID", row["BID"].ToString());
        writer.WriteElementString("Name", name);

    }
    else
    {
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement("Root");
        writer.WriteElementString("BID", "Error");
    }
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Close();

    conn.Close();
}
tbl.Dispose();
```